# Console winserv 2016 codepage

Tags: console, freepascal, windows-server, codepages

I have a problem, can't understand why my app doesn't reveal cyrillic text in console with correct codepage. On Win 10 there is ok, but on win serv 2016  there is a problem, I see diagraphs instead cyrillic symbols. Instaling RU Language Pack doesn't help, and switching  font to Lucide Console doesn't help too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Did you try starting one with cmd /w ?